# How to sort values in array and keep keys as it was?

Tags: php

So I've array which looks like this

```
Array ( [1] => 150 [2] => 190 [3] => 170 [6] => 160 [7] => 180 )
```

And want to receive it sorted but keep keys same. Smth like this:

```
Array ( [1] => 150 [2] => 160 [3] => 170 [6] => 180 [7] => 190 )
```

I tried a lot of php functions for array sorting but cant get right result. Help pls

Comment: `$keys = array_keys($input); $values = array_values($input); sort($values); $output = array_combine($keys,$values);` - I fail to see any practical use for this, but there you go.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, God bless you friend. Thank you!